# Spacing between bars or labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

so I'm trying to set the spacing between x labels or somehow make spaces between every bar in every subplot in the chart so that they wouln't overlap eachother even a little bit. I've tried rotating but some of the x labels are still overlapping and it doesn't look right. How can I make it more visually appealing?

```
g=sns.factorplot(x='type1', col='type2',col_wrap=3, data=dframe, kind='count', sharex=False, sharey=False, palette=pokemon_color_palette)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(60)


for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel('type1', color='indianred')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: example charts]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you shrink the size of the tick labels.

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you turn the labels 90°? That way they will never overlap.

```
    label.set_rotation(60)
```

Result:

[image]

Also you could not show the xlabel when there is no pokemon with those types.

Comment: Hmm actually thats good idea, however I was thinking if such thing was doable other (hard) way and I was missing something.

Comment: Oh I have another question, do you know how to actually change the rotation for just one of those charts? Like I want to rotate differently the second one only.

Comment: When you tour them, you are iterating over each one (g.axes.flat is a list). Just do it for the second item.

Comment: Code for anyone interested: `for label in g.axes.flat[1].get_xticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(120)`